# Beginner C++ Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a small amount of experience with C, but zero experience with OOP and am trying to solve a HackerRank problem in C++ on inheritance. I think I messed up somewhere in how the derived class is supposed to be defined because my `average` variable is not calculating properly. Also I'm not even sure how to print a test case to debug because when I add a `cout` statement to `calculate()` it doesn't do anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// given this definition  
class Person{
    protected:
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        int id;
    public:
        Person(string firstName, string lastName, int identification){
            this->firstName = firstName;
            this->lastName = lastName;
            this->id = identification;
        }
        void printPerson(){
            cout<< "Name: "<< lastName << ", "<< firstName <<"\nID: "<< id << "\n"; 
        }

};

// this is what I'm supposed to be creating
class Student :  public Person{
    private:
        vector<int> testScores;  
    public:
    Student(string firstName, string lastName, int id, vector<int> testScores) : Person(firstName,lastName, id) 
    {};

    char calculate(){
        double average = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < testScores.size(); i++){
            average += testScores[i];
            cout << average;
        }
        average = average / testScores.size();
            if ((average >= 90) && (average <= 100))
                return 'O';
            else if ((average >= 80) && (average < 90))
                return 'E';
            else if ((average >= 70) && (average < 80))
                return 'A';
            else if ((average >= 55) && (average < 70))
                return 'P';
            else if ((average >= 40) && (average < 55))
                return 'D';
            else if (average < 40)
                return 'T';
            else 
                return 'X'; // always returns this??
    }

};

// also given this main
int main() {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int id;
    int numScores;
    cin >> firstName >> lastName >> id >> numScores;
    vector<int> scores;
    for(int i = 0; i < numScores; i++){
        int tmpScore;
        cin >> tmpScore;
        scores.push_back(tmpScore);
    }
    Student* s = new Student(firstName, lastName, id, scores);
    s->printPerson();
    cout << "Grade: " << s->calculate() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Student's constructor does not copy testScores into Student's testScores.

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't routinely use `new`. `Student s(firstName, lastName, id, scores);` is fine.

Comment: On a side note, forget about HackerRank. I recently looked into those challenges out of curiosity, they are simply terrible.

Comment: I didn't write the `main()` function that includes `new` so you'll have to let them know ;) Any suggestions besides HR? I'm trying to learn a bit of algorithms, data structures, c++, python, java, and some probability programming over the summer. Their domains list includes all these so I thought it would be a good resource.

Comment: If you choose different parameter names, you won't have to use the `this->` syntax.

Comment: And you don't have to do *either* if you fully use a member-initializer list.

Comment: Not sure what a member-initializer list is. It gave me the `Person{}` and `main()` definitions and they're not editable, but I wouldn't mind knowing what that is for the future.

Comment: Why are you trying to write C++ before learning C++? That makes no sense. Pick up a good C++ book and _learn_!

Comment: I'm in an MSEE program struggling in some courses due to my lack of programming knowledge and I have a very short amount of time to catch up. I don't have time to read C++ books before even starting to attempt problems. I'm trying to do HackerRank as a sort of crash course. I usually learn better by example than by theory anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you give to your constructor the scores that you've read from the console:

```
 Student* s = new Student(firstName, lastName, id, scores);
```

Unfortunately, in your class, you don't use it to initialize the scores of the Student object:

```
Student(string firstName, string lastName, int id, vector<int> testScores)
       : Person(firstName,lastName, id) 
{};   // ouch testScores is lost
```

Just ccopy construct your sutdent's vector like this:

```
Student(string firstName, string lastName, int id, vector<int> testScores)
       : Person(firstName,lastName, id), testScores(testScores) 
{};
```

### Other remarks not related to your issue

If you create an object with `new`, you should think of `delete`-ing it somewhere (later you'll certainly learn about smart poitners like unique_ptr or shared_ptr, which will take care for you.)

You could avoid the `this->`  in `Person`'s constructor, using the mem-initializer as you did in `Student`:

```
   Person(string firstName, string lastName, int identification)
       : firstName(firstName), lastName(lastName), id(identification)
   {  // this code starts once all the members are constructed
   }
```